# knockoutjs, observable array not observed when modified through a custom binding

Tags: knockout.js

I have a custom binding that creates event handlers on init. In those event handlers, I call a function of my view model that updates one of my view model property (which is an observable array).

However the DOM elements that are bound to this property are not updated.

Furhermore, if I change the view model property by calling directly a method of the view model, the DOM elements are updated correclty. Also, if the property was changed using the first method prior, now the view model property contains all the rigth information.

Sorry if this is not clear, here is fiddle to test it: http://jsfiddle.net/8RTjN/67/
When running it, select a row (the viewmodel is updated but bindings are not), then click the add button (which modifies directly the viewmodel property) and now the bindings are updated correctly.

So: What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you push to `selectedRequests` you currently have

```
this.selectedRequests().push(request);
```

You do not need the ()

```
this.selectedRequests.push(request);
```

Comment: Aaaah, now it's working! Thanks so much!  If I understand correctly, it is because it is the observable array that implements that push method (which then propagates to other binding).  Whereas when using property().push, it is the push function of the javascript array (and that one does not propagate).  Is that right?

Comment: Yes that is correct, by putting in the () you are evaluating down to the base array and skipping the bindings.